# ms access - like keyword is not working in winform

Tags: winforms, ms-access

Below is my query, If I remove like condition it is working fine and even equals to also working but when I give Like it is not working. Please tell me what wrong I am doing here

```
select ID,CustomerName from Master where CustomerName='Something' // This is working or records found

select ID,CustomerName from Master where CustomerName Like '*Something*' // This is not working or no records found
```

I am using OleDb in winform

Comment: Try `%` instead of `*`

Comment: Hey thanks, this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access uses Jet-SQL dialect and your query will work in it and when you use it's provider

```
select ID,CustomerName from Master where CustomerName Like '*Something*'
```

You use OleDB provider and need to use its' syntax, `%` means `*` and `_` means `?` in search pattern for `LIKE` operator

```
select ID,CustomerName from Master where CustomerName Like '%Something%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all access sql is standard.  please try: double quotes, like this:

```
select ID,CustomerName from Master where CustomerName Like "*Something*"
```

Comment: I tried this but didnt work. Thanks for your answer % is worked for me

Comment: no problem.  
Keep in mind that if you process names that may have a single quote in them, you will need to use the double quotes.